# Bash parameter for script

Tags: bash, parameters, exec, launch

I would like to execute a program that launches, asks for a number, and then output my number reversed.

For example:

```
bob@bobby:~$ ./programm 
Number: 123456
654321 !
bob@bobby:~$`
```

How could i create a bash script, to execute the program with a chosen number? It's like I execute the program like that `./programm 123456` but I can't put my number in parameter, so is there a way to launch the program then autowrite my choosen number, then validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument passed to the command will be found in the positional parameter `$1`. As pointed out in the comments, you can use the `rev` command to reverse the order of the characters in the string. Your script might look something like

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s !" "$(rev "$1")"
```